# Installing digital certificate on Ubuntu Chromium

Tags: chromium, certificates

I'm using Linux Ubuntu 20.04 with Chromium Version 115.0.5790.170 (Official Build) snap (64-bit).

I need to use this digital certificate (it's called idCAT for people in Catalonia), but I've never used one before and have no idea how to install it. It's supposed to be [compatible with Ubuntu Mozilla Firefox](https://suport-idcat.aoc.cat/hc/en-gb/articles/4417343950609-Compatibility-of-the-idCAT-with-operating-systems-and-applications), but I wondered if it might be compatible with Chromium as well (just that they had not tested it).

The [instructions for downloading and installing the public keys](https://suport-idcat.aoc.cat/hc/en-gb/articles/4417343960337-How-to-download-and-install-the-idCAT-Certificate) are missing for Linux, so I'm not sure what to do. I've seen [this SuperUser post about adding a certificate to Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/437330/how-do-you-add-a-certificate-authority-ca-to-ubuntu), but I'm not sure it's correct for this idCAT certificate, and it's also quite technical. So if anyone has done this before, I would be so grateful if you could tell me how!

I'm not super familiar with Ubuntu as I just got this laptop in March but happy to do command line stuff if instructions are fairly explicit. Thanks!!